# App skeleton with UINavigationController outside of AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Still a newbie when it comes to navigation controllers I have ran into a problem I cant solve for my iPhone App. Instead of trying to solve current issues with too much code in too many files I thought I would take another approach.

What I want is a something similar to a tabBarController, but without the tab bars as they take too much space. So I thought of a skeleton with the following structure.
[alt text http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/2534/1007080002.jpg](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/2534/1007080002.jpg)

The SwitchViewController would have a method to switch between the MainView and the SettingsView. SettingsView could be a navigation controller (with a table view) that could drill in to next level of detail.

What would be the best approach to get this up and running? All tutorials I have seen have the navigation controller in the App Delegate, which I think would not work here?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with the Utility App template. Think "Stocks" application.

Comment: Thanks falconcreek. Had a look at it but I can't really get my head around it. Guess there are still a few things for a newbie like me to learn ;-) Might go for a single navigation tree as I learned that you could hide the navigationbar in the root one, which I need. But thanks anyway.